# Reshape dataframe to have column headers and their respective values in one row

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
Boat  <- c("Green, Blue", "Green", "Blue","Pink, Blue, Green","Blue","Blue, Green")
Car <- c("White","White","","","White","")
Train <-c("Grey","","Grey","Grey","","Grey")
df <-data.frame(ID,Boat,Car,Train)
```

which gives the table below

```
ID      Boat              Car            Train
1   Green, Blue          White          Grey
2      Green             White   
3      Blue                             Grey
4   Pink, Blue, Green                   Grey
5   Blue                 White
6   Blue, Green                         Grey
```

Is there a way I can reshape the data so that it gives the following output?

```
ID    Vehicle     Color
1     Boat        Green
1     Boat        Blue
1     Car         White
1     Train       Grey
2     Boat        Green
2     Car         White
3     Boat        Blue
3     Train       Grey
4     Boat        Pink
4     Boat        Green
4     Boat        Blue
4     Train       Grey
5     Boat        Blue
5     Car         White
6     Boat        Green
6     Boat        Blue
6     Train       Grey
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option. First we `pivot_longer`, then we split the column based on ",", then we `unnest_longer` and filter out results without any colors. Ideally, you could use `values_transform` in `pivot_longer`, but I could not get that to work.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = "Vehicle",  values_to = "Color") %>%
  mutate(Color = str_split(Color, ",")) %>%
  unnest_longer(Color) %>%
  filter(Color != "")
#> # A tibble: 17 x 3
#>       ID Vehicle Color   
#>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   
#>  1     1 Boat    "Green" 
#>  2     1 Boat    " Blue" 
#>  3     1 Car     "White" 
#>  4     1 Train   "Grey"  
#>  5     2 Boat    "Green" 
#>  6     2 Car     "White" 
#>  7     3 Boat    "Blue"  
#>  8     3 Train   "Grey"  
#>  9     4 Boat    "Pink"  
#> 10     4 Boat    " Blue" 
#> 11     4 Boat    " Green"
#> 12     4 Train   "Grey"  
#> 13     5 Boat    "Blue"  
#> 14     5 Car     "White" 
#> 15     6 Boat    "Blue"  
#> 16     6 Boat    " Green"
#> 17     6 Train   "Grey"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @AndS.! This was the best solution for my data :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'stack' function.

It will move your column headers into a column.
You can then rename the new columns as usual.

`df_new <- stack(df)`

More info:
http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/stack-and-unstack-function-in-r/

Comment: Have you tested this @tomanizer? It does not give the desired output.

Comment: Thank you @tomanizer! It didn't give the exact output I wanted - but thank you for responding and for telling me about the 'stack' function :) Good to know about it for future use :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse solution:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

separate(df, Boat, into = paste0("Boat", 1:3), sep = ", ", fill = "left") %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value) & nzchar(value)) %>%
  transmute(ID, Vehicle = gsub("\\d", "", name), Color = value)
#> # A tibble: 17 x 3
#>       ID Vehicle Color
#>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>
#>  1     1 Boat    Green
#>  2     1 Boat    Blue 
#>  3     1 Car     White
#>  4     1 Train   Grey 
#>  5     2 Boat    Green
#>  6     2 Car     White
#>  7     3 Boat    Blue 
#>  8     3 Train   Grey 
#>  9     4 Boat    Pink 
#> 10     4 Boat    Blue 
#> 11     4 Boat    Green
#> 12     4 Train   Grey 
#> 13     5 Boat    Blue 
#> 14     5 Car     White
#> 15     6 Boat    Blue 
#> 16     6 Boat    Green
#> 17     6 Train   Grey
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `pivot_longer` from the `tidyverse`. You can read more about pivoting in [this vignette](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html).

```r
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
Boat  <- c("Green, Blue", "Green", "Blue","Pink, Blue, Green","Blue","Blue, Green")
Car <- c("White","White","","","White","")
Train <-c("Grey","","Grey","Grey","","Grey")
df <-data.frame(ID,Boat,Car,Train)


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Boat, Car, Train),
               names_to = "Vehicle", 
               values_to = "Color"
  )
#> # A tibble: 18 x 3
#>       ID Vehicle Color              
#>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>              
#>  1     1 Boat    "Green, Blue"      
#>  2     1 Car     "White"            
#>  3     1 Train   "Grey"             
#>  4     2 Boat    "Green"            
#>  5     2 Car     "White"            
#>  6     2 Train   ""                 
#>  7     3 Boat    "Blue"             
#>  8     3 Car     ""                 
#>  9     3 Train   "Grey"             
#> 10     4 Boat    "Pink, Blue, Green"
#> 11     4 Car     ""                 
#> 12     4 Train   "Grey"             
#> 13     5 Boat    "Blue"             
#> 14     5 Car     "White"            
#> 15     5 Train   ""                 
#> 16     6 Boat    "Blue, Green"      
#> 17     6 Car     ""                 
#> 18     6 Train   "Grey"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I'd also suggest using `NA_character_` instead of an empty string.

Comment: Thank you @maia-sh! It didn't give the exact output I wanted, but thank you for responding!

Answer (score 1):

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
Boat  <- c("Green, Blue", "Green", "Blue","Pink, Blue, Green","Blue","Blue, Green")
Car <- c("White","White","","","White","")
Train <-c("Grey","","Grey","Grey","","Grey")
df <-data.frame(ID,Boat,Car,Train) %>% 
   separate(Boat, into =paste0("Boat", 1:3), sep = ', ')

df2 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, 
               names_to = 'Vehicle', 
               values_to = 'Color'
    ) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Color)) %>%
mutate(Vehicle = str_remove(Vehicle,"[\\d-]"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to achieve this is a combination of `pivot_longer` and `separate_rows` from the [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) package:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = "Vehicle", values_to = "Color") %>% 
  separate_rows(Color) %>% 
  filter(Color != "")
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 17 x 3
      ID Vehicle Color
   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>
 1     1 Boat    Green
 2     1 Boat    Blue 
 3     1 Car     White
 4     1 Train   Grey 
 5     2 Boat    Green
 6     2 Car     White
 7     3 Boat    Blue 
 8     3 Train   Grey 
 9     4 Boat    Pink 
10     4 Boat    Blue 
11     4 Boat    Green
12     4 Train   Grey 
13     5 Boat    Blue 
14     5 Car     White
15     6 Boat    Blue 
16     6 Boat    Green
17     6 Train   Grey
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table` you can do something like:

```
library(data.table)
melt(as.data.table(df), 1)[, list(trimws(unlist(strsplit(value, ",")))), .(ID, variable)][order(ID)]
#     ID variable    V1
#  1:  1     Boat Green
#  2:  1     Boat  Blue
#  3:  1      Car White
#  4:  1    Train  Grey
#  5:  2     Boat Green
#  6:  2      Car White
#  7:  3     Boat  Blue
#  8:  3    Train  Grey
#  9:  4     Boat  Pink
# 10:  4     Boat  Blue
# 11:  4     Boat Green
# 12:  4    Train  Grey
# 13:  5     Boat  Blue
# 14:  5      Car White
# 15:  6     Boat  Blue
# 16:  6     Boat Green
# 17:  6    Train  Grey
```

Using `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package makes the code a little shorter with the same result:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(melt(as.data.table(df), 1), "value", ",", "long")[order(ID)]
#     ID variable value
#  1:  1     Boat Green
#  2:  1     Boat  Blue
#  3:  1      Car White
#  4:  1    Train  Grey
#  5:  2     Boat Green
# ... <<SNIP>> ...
# 14:  5      Car White
# 15:  6     Boat  Blue
# 16:  6     Boat Green
# 17:  6    Train  Grey
```

Comment: Hi @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1! Thank you again for your reply :) Your splitstackshape package is really useful!